# Extend Header (logo, search box and cart) in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, header, logo

I am trying to extend the Header (logo, search box and cart), but those files are the different location. I don't know how to adjust those. Could you please suggest me on this.

[image]

Comment: exactly what do you want to do?

Comment: @Rakesh logo should be left search box should be middle and cart should be right. Is it possible to these codes comes under one file?

Comment: This not possible to come these code in one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change below style:

```
.header.content {
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.block-search {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.minicart-wrapper {
    float: none;
}
```

Change below code in `Magento_Checkout\layout\default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="top.search" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
```

Answer (score 2):

The search position is set in the `magento-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` but the issue is that the minicart is set to have the position after "logo" you need to change this in `magento-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
```

change to

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="top.search" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
```

and after this style the top search so it shouldn't be with a `float: right;` ( adapt the style as you like )

Also, it is recomanded to make the changes for the checkout module files in `app/design/frontend/YOUR_COMPANY/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
Move search box follow step :

step-1 :- opne Admin 
step-2 :- CONTENT > Block > Home Page Block > show - hide edit button click
```

add css in style tag

.header.content {
    text-align: center;
}
.block-search {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}